# Compose a Twitter DM without displaying dialog

Tags: ios, twitter

I see @Cirrostratus answer at
[iOS 5 Twitter Framework: Tweeting without user input and confirmation (modal view controller)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423447/ios-5-twitter-framework-tweeting-without-user-input-and-confirmation-modal-vie) and it works nicely for a tweet. How would I alter this to send a DM instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
    NSString *dmString = @"d @RecipientTwitterName ";
    NSString *statusString = [dmString stringByAppendingString:stringForTweet];

   postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"]
                                     parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:statusString forKey:@"status"]
                                  requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];
```

just prepend the d and your recipient's twitter name.