# TWRequest is deprecated in iOS 6.0 - what can I use instead?

Tags: ios, twrequest, social-framework

I'm developing a Twitter Feed View for an iOS App. I found TWRequest and it works exactly like that which i was looking for. But: i get an Notice: "TWRequest is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0". What should I use instead?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

On iOS 6 you should use the `Social.framework`. This has a class named `SLRequest`.

You use it almost in the same way as the deprecated `TWRequest`, but you need to specify that it's a twitter request as opposed to a facebook request.

The entire `Twitter.framework` became deprecated as of iOS 6, since Apple added Facebook and Weibo (a Chinese social network) to iOS 6, they grouped all social classes into the new `Social.framework`.

Note you must specify the service type for Twitter/Facebook, Example:

```
SLRequest *aRequest  = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                    URL:myurl
                                             parameters:myparams];
```

Be sure to check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a complete code to upload text + image to your Twitter Account using Twitter api**

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterImage.png"];
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
            NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {
                ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": @"From my app"};
                NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];
                SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest
                                                  requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                  URL:requestURL parameters:message];
                NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
                [postRequest addMultipartData:data withName:@"media" type:@"image/png" filename:@"TestImage"];
                postRequest.account = acct;

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:
                     ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse
                       *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                     {
                         if (error) {
                             NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                         }
                         else {
                             NSLog(@"Upload Sucess !");
                         }
                     }];
            }
        }
    }];
```

Comment: 2015:  Use "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" and also note that errors quite possibly may come back as JSON in the responseData.

Answer (score 0):

In case you plan on integrating TwitterKit by Twitter to perform the tweets via your custom twitter app then this might help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28602749/1740354

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use Twitter API. You should have Twitter framework for that.

Then do following code:

```
NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"status": @"Hello, my first autopost tweet..."};

    NSError *clientError;
    NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                             URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                             URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                             parameters:params
                             error:&clientError];

    if (request) {
        [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
         sendTwitterRequest:request
         completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                      NSData  *data,
                      NSError *connectionError) {
             if (data) {
                 // handle the response data e.g.
                 NSError *jsonError;
                 NSDictionary *dicResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                               JSONObjectWithData:data
                                               options:0
                                               error:&jsonError];
                 NSLog(@"%@",[dicResponse description]);
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Error code: %ld | Error description: %@", (long)[connectionError code], [connectionError localizedDescription]);
             }
         }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
    }
```