# How to autopost on twitter in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, autopostback

I want to auto post my static link in twitter using iphone application (without using dialog box, cancel option , send option). is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea? It would likely be against Twitter's Terms of Service.

Comment: ya, you can do that with the use of TWRequest, deployment target must be 5.0 or more

Answer (score 1):

I Found this links for this:

Post in iOS 5 with [TWRequest](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-5-twitter-framework-part-2.html)

Post in iOS 6+ with [SLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330596/twrequest-is-deprecated-in-ios-6-0-what-can-i-use-instead)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method of Twitter Framework:

```
NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"status": @"Hello, my first autopost tweet..."};

    NSError *clientError;
    NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                             URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                             URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                             parameters:params
                             error:&clientError];

    if (request) {
        [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
         sendTwitterRequest:request
         completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                      NSData  *data,
                      NSError *connectionError) {
             if (data) {
                 // handle the response data e.g.
                 NSError *jsonError;
                 NSDictionary *dicResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                               JSONObjectWithData:data
                                               options:0
                                               error:&jsonError];
                 NSLog(@"%@",[dicResponse description]);
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Error code: %ld | Error description: %@", (long)[connectionError code], [connectionError localizedDescription]);
             }
         }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
    }
```