# IOS can't reply status with status_id

Tags: ios, twitter

I want to reply to twitter status with status id. but i get http response 403.
Here my code. I can sent first tweet. I get it's id. But when i want sent reply to first tweet with it's id i get http response 403.  What is my wrong.

```
 - (IBAction)btnSendToucUpInside:(id)sender {

    __block NSDecimalNumber *tid;
    __block int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (i == 0  || _birlestirilsinMi) {
            urlParametres = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.twitArray objectAtIndex:0]], @"status", nil];
        }else{
            urlParametres = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.twitArray objectAtIndex:0]], @"status",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tid], @"in_reply_to_status_id",@"true", @"include_entities", nil];
        }
        TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:urlParametres requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

        [postRequest setAccount:[twitAccountArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
         {
             if (responseData) {
                 i++;
                 NSDictionary *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                 tid = TWData[@"id"];
                 NSLog(@"%@",tid);

                 //show status after done
                 NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                 NSLog(@"Twiter post status : %@", output);
             }
         }];

        if (i == _twitArray.count -1) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 403 means unauthorized, double check what is in `[twitAccountArray objectAtIndex:0]` maybe?

Comment: @VincentG i checked. i sent tweets without loop i can sent each post.

Comment: i debugged and i get error: duplicate status in responsedata

Comment: Then maybe simply Twitter reject that you post twice the same message? :)

Comment: Yes. I think problem is while loop. Because while loop don't wait response. But i don't know another way. have you any solution about this @VincentG

Comment: Remove that `while`, I have no idea what you want to do with `_twitArray`, but that `while(true)`/`break` pattern sending requestS is a mistake.

Comment: twitArray include my tweets. I want to sent this array objects as tweet. But I want to do as ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending repeatedly the same message to twitter, your loop being erratic and not using properly your `twitArray` variable. Make sure to use `twitArray` when building your `TWRequest` instances. You need something like:

```
for (NSString *twit in twitArray) {
    ...
    urlParametres = @{ @"status" : twit }
    ...
}
```

instead of using `[self.twitArray objectAtIndex:0]` at each iteration...

---

Also take care of `TWRequest` : [TWRequest is deprecated in iOS 6.0 - what can I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13330596/517832)

---

Kinda off-topic, but `while(true)` + `break` is a really bad practice, almost as bad as using `goto`, you definitely should use something like:

```
for (NSString *twit in twitArray) {...}
```

Or if you need a reversed order:

```
for (NSString *twit in twitArray.reverseObjectEnumerator) {...}
```