# Tweet, without using the tweet sheet

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I'm using below code to share the content (from `UITextView`, `UIImageView`) through twitter

```
-(void)shareViaTweet:(NSString *)shareMessage{
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",shareMessage]];
    if (self.imageString)
    {
        [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageString]];
    }

    if (self.urlString)
    {
        [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]];
    }
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                              message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}

}
```

But I need share this, without using the pop up view (I think tweet sheet). It's happening because the below code,

```
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I click the button "Share" of my app, I need to post that in twitter.

Edited:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
NSString *message = messageTextView.text;
//hear before posting u can allow user to select the account
NSArray *arrayOfAccons = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
for(ACAccount *acc in arrayOfAccons)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",acc.username); //in this u can get all accounts user names provide some UI for user to select,such as UITableview
}


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com"
              @"/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];
             NSDictionary *params = @{@"screen_name" : message,
                                     @"forKey":@"status",
                                      @"trim_user" : @"1",
                                      @"count" : @"1"};
// Request access from the user to access their Twitter account

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)

 {
     if (granted == YES)
     {
         // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
         {
             //use the first account available
             ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0]; //hear this line replace with selected account. than post it :)




             SLRequest *request =
             [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                          URL:url
                                   parameters:params];


             //Post the request
             [request setAccount:acct];

             //manage the response
             [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
              {
                  if(error)
                  {
                      //if there is an error while posting the tweet
                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"Error in posting" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                      [alert show];

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      // on successful posting the tweet
                      NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"Successfully posted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                      [alert show];


                  }
              }];

         }
         else
         {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"You have no twitter account" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];

         }
     }
     else
     {
         //suppose user not set any of the accounts
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"Permission not granted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];

     }
 } ];


//[widgetsHandler closeWidget:nil];


//[self postImage:shareImageView.image withStatus:messageTextView.text];
}
```

**Update:** Error

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send images u need do something like this

```
  [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
   if (granted == YES)
    {
      // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
     NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
     if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
      {
           //use the first account available
       ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

       //create this request 
       SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com"@"/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"] parameters:  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"status"]];
       UIImage *imageToPost = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
       NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0f);//set the compression quality
      [postRequest addMultipartData:imageData withName:@"media" type:@"image/jpeg" filename:@"image.jpg"];

   //set account and same as above code 

....
 ....
```

Comment: It's giving me an error, see the edits. I go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778167/undocumented-nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-1001-1003-and-1004-using-storeki0) link. Yes, it's take lot more time to come to that error in debugging. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: did u set up all URLSchemes

Comment: It worked perfectly for me and i posted that code. It should work try a test project and post from it and see if it is posting or not

Comment: Where do I need to put consumer key, consumer secret codes in my application. May be that will be the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38078/discussion-between-shan-and-user2745507)

Answer (score 1):

if u wanna share the tweet without using the tweet sheet see my answer it will post on twitter wall without using the tweet sheet see [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459252/how-to-post-on-twitter-by-hiding-slcomposeviewcontroller-tweetsheettweet-instan/18460093#comment27141600_18460093) and also set the twitter account in the device. hope this helps

unfortunately the class `TWRequest` is deprecated in iOS 6 but alternatively we can use `SLRequest` present in the Social framework

the answer for this is similar to the old answer
i commented out something that i dont want but if u want to select which account to use then uncomment the commented code

```
 - (IBAction)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender
    {
      ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
      ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
      NSString *message = _textView.text;

    //    NSArray *arrayOfAccons = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
    //    for(ACAccount *acc in arrayOfAccons)
    //    {
    //        NSLog(@"%@",acc.username);
    //        NSDictionary *properties = [acc dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"properties"]];
    //        NSDictionary *details = [properties objectForKey:@"properties"];
    //        NSLog(@"user name = %@",[details objectForKey:@"fullName"]);
    //        NSLog(@"user_id  =  %@",[details objectForKey:@"user_id"]);
    //    }


    // Request access from the user to access their Twitter account
    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
    {
        if (granted == YES)
        {
         // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
            NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
             {
               //use the first account available
               ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

               // Build a twitter request
               // TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:
               // [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"status"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST]; //commented the  deprecated method of TWRequest class

             SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"status"]]; //use this method instead



             //Post the request
             [postRequest setAccount:acct];//set account

             //manage the response
             [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
              {
                 if(error)
                  {
                      //if there is an error while posting the tweet
                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"Error in posting" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                      [alert show];
                      [alert release];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      // on successful posting the tweet
                      NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"Successfully posted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                      [alert show];
                      [alert release];

                  }
              }];

         }
         else
         {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"You have no twitter account" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];
         }
     }
     else
     {
         //suppose user not set any of the accounts
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"You have no twitter account" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         [alert release];
     }
 } ];

[account release];

 }
```

Comment: The method name,

`[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)`

and


`TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:
                                       [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"]
                                                          parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"status"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];`

are deprecated, can you help me with that?

Comment: did u added  #import <Social/Social.h> #import <Accounts/Accounts.h> #import <Twitter/Twitter.h> #import <Social/SLRequest.h>  all these headers and also frameworks

Comment: ya, but this is the way without using tweet sheet that i followed.

Comment: try setting "SLRequestMethodPOST" in ur code. U are using "SLRequestMethodGET"

Comment: No, But it says "Successfully posted" Do I need to add Twitter App ID or something else where. See the edits.

Comment: Code is working perfectly, it identify the users also. but the post is not there. Do I need to login to the twitter, inside from my app?
Your is greatly appreciated

Comment: No need to login to account it just will just post.

Comment: wait i tested it using "SLRequest" it is posting successfully and i got posted message perfectly wait i will post my code

Comment: @user2745507 let me know if u are facing any problem

Comment: Great,Thanks @Shan, It work perfectly. There's a thing, can you help me with attaching an image(s) to this post.

Comment: Hmm wait i will check

Comment: i posted the new answer for posting images and i am also suggesting u to go through this  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/posting-images-using-twrequest