# iOS retweet with SLRequest returns bad URL error

Tags: ios, twitter, slrequest

I'm implementing a retweet functionality but I keep getting a bad URL error after my POST.
Here's my code:

```
SLRequest *twitterRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/%@.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tweetId forKey:@"id"]];

[twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
        NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
        return;
    }

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }

  });
}];
```

Any ideas? Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. I forgot to pass the string when creating the request "...%@.json".

i.e.

```
SLRequest *twitterRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/%@.json",@"490794578250059776"]] parameters:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

insted of this

```
   SLRequest *twitterRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/%@.json"] parameters [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tweetId forKey:@"id"]];
```

try this

```
 SLRequest *twitterRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/%@.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tweetId forKey:@"status"]];
```

one thing u can not repost the same message again and again it will consider as spam 
and also see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650837/tweet-without-using-the-tweet-sheet/18650975#18650975) probably u may miss something

Comment: I tried it and also looked at your code from the link and I get a 403 every time.

Comment: did u set up the account in your device

Comment: I did but I just realized what I did wrong. Actually, my code was correct, with the exception that I forgot to pass the string :p

Comment: May be u reached the update limit , see this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

Answer (score 0):

You should attach an account to your request.

```
// create a request
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                  URL:url
                                           parameters:@{@"screen_name":@"nst021"}];

// attach an account to the request
NSArray *twitterAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];
[request setAccount:[twitterAccounts lastObject]];

// execute the request
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                     NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,
                                     NSError *error) {
    // caution, you're on an arbitrary queue here...
}
```