# How can i post on twitter without showing dialogue in ios?

Tags: ios, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

I want to post my status on twitter. I want to add an image, but I dont want a share dialogue.

Instead I'd like an interface like Instagram, where the user just selects twitter and presses 'share', so it's easy.

Here is my running code so far:

```
//  Create an instance of the Tweet Sheet
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                       composeViewControllerForServiceType:
                                       SLServiceTypeTwitter];

// Sets the completion handler.  Note that we don't know which thread the
// block will be called on, so we need to ensure that any required UI
// updates occur on the main queue
tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    switch(result) {
            //  This means the user cancelled without sending the Tweet
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            break;
            //  This means the user hit 'Send'
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            break;
    }
};

//  Set the initial body of the Tweet
[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Socia"];

//  Adds an image to the Tweet.  For demo purposes, assume we have an
//  image named 'larry.png' that we wish to attach
if (![tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon120x120.png"]]) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to add the image!");
}

//  Add an URL to the Tweet.  You can add multiple URLs.
if (![tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title="]]){
    NSLog(@"Unable to add the URL!");
}

//  Presents the Tweet Sheet to the user
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Tweet sheet has been presented.");
}];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tweet, without using the tweet sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650837/tweet-without-using-the-tweet-sheet)

Answer (score 2):

```
 [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
   if (granted == YES)
    {
      // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
     NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
     if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
      {
           //use the first account available
       ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

       //create this request 
       SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com"@"/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"] parameters:  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"status"]];
       UIImage *imageToPost = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
       NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0f);//set the compression quality
      [postRequest addMultipartData:imageData withName:@"media" type:@"image/jpeg" filename:@"image.jpg"];

   //set account and same as above code 

....
 ....
```

The above is from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19003046/1197966) and this code worked for me.

Here you can find how to post Twitter's updates with media [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media).

Comment: This should almost be a comment instead of an answer. What happens when that SO link or the twitter link stop working?

Comment: That's true! But i can't post comments yet :)

Comment: next time post some code. that way if those links do expire, people still have a reference.

Comment: @MartinoBonfiglioli after implementing this code alert show that posted successfully and when i saw on my account nothing is there and giving me an error when i saw nslog "Twitter response, HTTP response: 400" Please tell me how can i handle this ?