# Twitter integration in iOS without dialog

Tags: ios, twitter

i am integrating twitter in my iOS app and and found the answer from stack overflow and other resources. but i have a question if iOS device user does not add any twitter account, how can we implement this case. i have seen in android app that they can post text, images and links to twitter with login page with the help of web view -

[How can i post on twitter without showing dialogue in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912592/how-can-i-post-on-twitter-without-showing-dialogue-in-ios)

[iOS 5 Twitter Framework: Tweeting without user input and confirmation (modal view controller)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423447/ios-5-twitter-framework-tweeting-without-user-input-and-confirmation-modal-vie)

after searching related post now i know about both dialog and using request. but how can we handle the above case.

an advance thanks

Comment: can u show ur code and what the problem u meet

Comment: hi kartik, if there is no account ( ACAccount ) setup to iOS device for twitter app. so in this case can we authorise user from and post data to twitter ??

Comment: u need the single user login or multiple user login from twitter, I think your coding is fine, small problem in your settings page there is no twitter a/c, plz add one a/c in settings page and check once if u not get in the answer tell me

Comment: yes there is no account added to device. is there only one way to notify the user to add an a/c ??? or can we authorise user with twitter api without adding a/c ?

Comment: if u compare to Facebook app twitter app is better/best -- if u login via in your app or login any other app or login with twitter app or login with safari, the user details automatically added in the device settings, but Facebook it won't , so try any one of the above steps