# Twitter in iOS 6 & 7: Posting a tweet without user's confirmation

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, twitter

I am trying to integrate `Twitter` in my iOS application.

The application is expected to support `iOS versions 6.x & 7.x`.

I want to directly post a `tweet` once the user taps on a button in my `UI`, without again asking confirmation in `SLComposeViewController` alert.

I have gone through the following posts which say how to do that, problem being that they are both configured for `iOS 5.x`.

[Stack Overflow Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423447/ios-5-twitter-framework-tweeting-without-user-input-and-confirmation-modal-vie)

[Stack Overflow Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459252/how-to-post-on-twitter-by-hiding-slcomposeviewcontroller-tweetsheettweet-instan)

How exactly do I go about it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the problem? iOS 5.x code will works mostly perfect on never iOS.

Comment: Nope, some of the API's have changed!!

Answer (score 0):

I see no differences from [iOS 5.1 to iOS 6.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011959), neither [iOS 6.1 to 7.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html) for Twitter api.

Use the iOS 5 tutorials and check with alt+left mouse click to inform about deprications or modified functions if there are.

[Maybe this will help.](http://reagentx.net/new/how-to-tweet-from-an-ios-app-without-using-tweetsheet-2)

Answer (score 0):

In the two links you mentioned they are using Twitter Api v1. which is deprecated a long time ago: [API V1 no longer function](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1) instead you should be using the V1.1 so the url to post a tweet will be `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json`

In addition `TWRequest` is also deprecated in iOS 6.0 you should use `SLRequest`

**Here is a simple code to do so:**

```
- (void) sendTweetWithoutPromp:(NSString*) tweetText
{
    NSString *url = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [params setObject:tweetText forKey:@"status"];

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted)
        {
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            if ([accountsArray count] > 0)
            {
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest  requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] parameters:params ];

                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                 {
                     NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                     NSLog(@"output = %@",output);
                     dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         if (error)
                         {

                         }

                     });
                 }];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"no Account in Settings");
            }
        }
    }];

}
```